# Using multiple instances of pagination with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vue-component

I would like to use multiple instances of Vue.js's Pagination plugin inside of a loop.

For example

```
for (let i in sources) {
    // create a new tab with its own pagination
}
```

The issue im running into is that the `@page-changed="pageChanged"` method only sends in the new page number, so I don't know which tab store to update. If i try sending in the store name to the function `pageChanged`, it overwrites the new page number so I still can't update the store.

Is there a way to identify which store is calling pageChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uses `@page-changed="pageChanged($event, i)"`.

`$event` is the page# value emitted from pagination plugin.

`i` is the index from `for (let i in sources)`.

Then in the function=pageChanged, you will know which tab (=sources[i]) received the @page-changed event.

**The Pseudocode will be:**

or you can pass the tab object to pageChanged like `@page-changed="pageChanged($event, tab)"`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(tab, tabIndex) in sources" :key="index">
      <v-tab :data="tab">
        <v-pagination @page-changed="pageChanged($event, tabIndex)"></v-pagination>
      </v-tab>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
  return {
    sources: ['tab1', 'tab2']
  },
  methods: {
    pageChanged: function (data, tabIndex) {
      // update something for this.sources[tabIndex]
    }
  }
}
}
</script>
```